# Bootstrap 4 Dropdown Menu & Carousel Not Working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

I just started with Bootstrap4 and I am implementing Carousel & Dropdown menu in a website. But both don't seem to work whenever I perform a click on the drop-down menu or carousel indicator it adds the id in URL and takes to the top of the page again. Following is the code.

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <!-- http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider/img/slide-2.jpg -->
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider/img/slide-2.jpg" alt="First slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>...</h5>
            <p>...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider/img/slide-2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>...</h5>
            <p>...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider/img/slide-2.jpg" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>...</h5>
            <p>...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've included all the required `CSS(bootstrap.min.css)` and `JS(jQuery, Popper, bootstrap.min.js)`

I don't know what's the problem. It's not even showing any kind of error or warning in the console too.

Comment: I think `data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"` would be taking you to the top of the page, try removing it.

Comment: if `id` is added in `URL` then `bootstrap.min.js` is not linked properly, Can you make show full code

Comment: @Saheb still the same error

Comment: @sanojlawrence you were correct there was a linking error please post this as an answer i'll mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify all links are linked properly, and your directing to exact file location or use `CDN`

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider/img/slide-2.jpg -->
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider/img/slide-2.jpg" alt="First slide">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>...</h5>
                <p>...</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider/img/slide-2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>...</h5>
                <p>...</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider/img/slide-2.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>...</h5>
                <p>...</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```